# Creating a new variable in dataset using ifelse() and exisiting data

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a new variable in a dataset based on if certain conditions of the observation are met. For example, I have a dataset like:

```
dataset <- read.table(text="var1 var2 var3
 67  Home  1
-55  Away  1
-36  Away  0 
 12  Home  0", header=TRUE)
```

and I want to create a variable dataset$var4 that takes the opposite of var1 (multiplies it by -1) if and only if var2 = "Away" and var3 = 1. If those conditions aren't met, I would like it to input the original value for var1 for that observation. My code looks like this:

```
dataset$var4 <- ifelse(dataset$var2 == "Away" & dataset$var3 == 1, dataset$var1*-1, dataset$var1)
```

With the example dataset above, the second observation should be the only one to change to its opposite (from -55 to 55). However, when I do this the none of the numbers change at all. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
To clarify, the conditions in the ifelse statement should be correct. That is, when I input:

```
which(dataset$var2 == "Away" & dataset$var3 == 1)
```

it returns "2" meaning the second observation is recognized to fit the conditions.

Comment: When I run your code, there is a new column `var4` created and the second value turned from -55 to 55 so it seems to be working for me. So you saying you are not getting an additional column in your `dataset` data.frame?

Comment: The second observation does change from -55 to 55. Maybe there's a typo in your R file?  because this code is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I figured out the issue. It was a dumb one too. My var3 variable was set as an integer variable instead of as a numeric variable and when I switched it, it worked for some reason.

```
dataset$var3 <- as.integer(dataset$var3)
```

That did the trick.

Comment: This should not make a difference. The same should work for both integer and numeric columns. There must be something else going on that has been omitted from the question.